# Clear/Refresh url after Get call from JSP

Tags: jsp, url, jakarta-ee, get

I want to know if it is possible to clear the URL after a Get call from jsp ?

I display a simple list in my jsp :

```
 <c:forEach items="${categories}" var="category">
                    <li>${category.categoryId}</li>
                    <li>${category.categoryName}</li>
                    <li><a href="./Admin?action=delete_category&id=${category.categoryId}">Delete</a><br/></li>
</c:forEach>
```

And this is my Servlet :

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        /** Some stuffs **/

       request.getRequestDispatcher("admin.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

So the URL at button click is always : `http:/myapp/Admin?action=delete_category&id=*`

And I have 2 Post submit forms into my page that are re-triggering this Get call..
So I need a method to clear the URL after the Get call.

Comment: Don't, ever, delete with GET. When googlebot will browse your app, it will follow every link and delete everything you have. When the user will refresh, it will try to delete again. Use the Post-Redirect-Get pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: ok but this will not be online so I dont care about good way to do it. But all examples are welcome

Comment: No example, thank you.